# OpenVPN connectivity issue with internal subnet

Tags: networking, server, vpn, openvpn, debian

I've setup a VPN server within a vlan with an internal subnet.
On the VPN server one VPN using IPSec is configured, which can connect to the internal subnet.

Additional I've installed an OpenVPN-Server but the clients can't connect to the internal subnet. The server configuration is:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-auth ta.key 0
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "route 10.16.0.0 255.255.0.0"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
```

The internal subnet is 10.16.0.0/16.

A traceroute from the connect client to an ip address in the internal subnet shows the following output:

```
traceroute to 10.16.15.13 (10.16.15.13), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.8.0.1 (10.8.0.1)  1.867 ms  1.757 ms  1.677 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
```

External connection with the connected client are working.

Output from `ip route list`:

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0 
default via VM-GATEWAY dev ens3 
10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.4 
10.16.0.0/16 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0 
VM-GATEWAY dev ens3 scope link 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0 
VM-IP via VM-GATEWAY dev ens3
```

Outfrom from `ifconfig` on the openvpn server:

```
ens19: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet OPENVPN-HOST-IP  netmask 255.255.255.248  broadcast OPENVPN-HOST-GATEWAY
    inet6 fe80::9883:beff:fe99:305e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 9a:83:be:99:30:5e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 6500104  bytes 3982668113 (3.7 GiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 7271114  bytes 4037705401 (3.7 GiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1  (Lokale Schleife)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ppp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1280
    inet 192.168.42.1  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 192.168.42.10
    ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Punkt-zu-Punkt-Verbindung)
    RX packets 208705  bytes 28271807 (26.9 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 189459  bytes 120966692 (115.3 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.16.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  destination 10.16.0.1
    inet6 fe80::f8ab:a6e:149f:eec4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
    RX packets 269  bytes 19394 (18.9 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 7  bytes 336 (336.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Output from `iptables -L`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
f2b-sshd   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Output from `ip addr list`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens18: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6e:3e:98:f6:26:2f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: ens19: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9a:83:be:99:30:5e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet OPENVPN-HOST-IP/29 brd OPENVPN-BROADCAST-IP scope global ens19
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.16.0.2/16 scope global ens19
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::9883:beff:fe99:305e/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: ip_vti0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
10: ppp0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1280 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 3
    link/ppp 
    inet 192.168.42.1 peer 192.168.42.10/32 scope global ppp0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
13: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 10.16.0.1/16 brd 10.16.255.255 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::4ef6:f672:4240:6eef/64 scope link flags 800 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Content of `/etc/openvpn/openvpn-status.log`:

```
OpenVPN CLIENT LIST
Updated,Tue Nov 27 19:38:12 2018
Common Name,Real Address,Bytes Received,Bytes Sent,Connected Since
vm-monitoring,CLIENT-IP:53718,4883,3650,Tue Nov 27 19:38:05 2018
ROUTING TABLE
Virtual Address,Common Name,Real Address,Last Ref
10.16.0.2,vm-monitoring,CLIENT-IP:53718,Tue Nov 27 19:38:07 2018
GLOBAL STATS
Max bcast/mcast queue length,1
END
```

Do you have an idea how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your openvpn server is on different subnet as the 10.16.0.0. Change your openvpn server line

```
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
```

to

```
server 10.16.0.0 255.255.0.0
```

and restart openvpn service.

install iptables, enable port 1194 on wan input chain:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
```

enable forwarding packets from 10.16.0.0 to lan zone:

```
iptables -I INPUT -i tun0 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -I FORWARD -i tun0 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -I OUTPUT -o tun0 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -I FORWARD -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
```

Enable internet access for connected vpn clients:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.16.0.0/16 -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: I've changed this configuration for testing purposes now without solving the problem. The first hop in traceroute is now vanished but I still can't reach other servers in this subnet

Comment: What firewall do you use? Iptables?

Comment: Do you have forwarding enabled in the kernel?

Comment: No firewall is active at the moment

Comment: Yes, forwarding is enabled

Comment: check the answer..

Comment: No, that doesn't solved my problem

Comment: What is the output of iptables -L now?

Comment: Is ens3 your virtual adapter?

Comment: What is the content of the openvpn-status.log?

Comment: I've added the output from iptables -L to the post. Yes, ens3 is the virtual adapter. I've added the output of ip addr list to the post too.

Comment: enter the iptables rules again and use iptables-save to save them.

Comment: can you ping 10.16.0.1?